# Как через js отправить на вебсервер запрос с данными

Tags: javascript, python

и так, у меня есть код

```js
<script>
        function sendinfo(token, channelID)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/readdirectmessage",
                type: "get",
                data: {jstoken: token, jsid: channelID},
                success: function(response) {
                },
                error: function(xhr) {
                    //Do Something to handle error
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

и

```
<p style="margin: 0px;">Channel: <button onclick='sendinfo("{{token}}", "{{card["channelID"]}}");' style="text-decoration: none;color: rgb(133, 133, 133);">{{card['channelID']}}</button></p>
```

так вот, при нажатии на кнопку я хочу чтобы функция sendinfo отправляла запрос на вебсервер, он это получает, но не отдаёт функцию `render_template`

вот небольшой код вебсервера (не бейте за говнокод)

```py
@app.route("/readdirectmessage", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def dmreader_read():
    token = request.args.get('jstoken')
    channelid = request.args.get('jsid')
    r = requests.get(f"https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/{channelid}/messages?limit=1", headers={"Authorization": token})
    ret_list = []
    exp = 0
    lastmsg = 0

    if r.status_code == 200:
        usr = requests.get("https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me", headers={"Authorization": token}).json()
        for i in r.json():
            ret_list.append(i)
            lastmsg=i["id"]
            exp+=1

        while True:
            ras = requests.get(
                f"https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/{channelid}/messages?before={lastmsg}&limit=100",
                headers={"Authorization": token})
            if (ras.text == "[]"):
                break

            for i in ras.json():
                ret_list.append(i)
                exp += 1
                try:
                    lastmsg = i["id"]
                except:
                    for l in i["id"]:
                        lastmsg = l

                if lastmsg == int(i["id"]):
                    break
        ret_list.append(r.json())

        return render_template("dmreader_read.html", msgstatus=json.loads('{"status":"ok","message":"Exported '+str(exp)+' messages"}'),
                               render=True, resp=reversed(ret_list), usr=usr)
    else:
        return "{'message': '401: Unauthorized', 'code': 0}", 401
```

Comment: я правда не знаю в чём проблема, с js я почти не работал

Comment: блин, как это сделать, иначе это удар по безопасности аккаунта в дискорде